# Different view.jsp for Frontend and ControlPanel

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, hook

I have hooked the ImageGallery Liferay Portlet to modify the layout of the gallery.

As I'm happy with the result I wanted to add some new pictures in the control panel and than - shock! The same view as in the frontend.

So i need a `<c:if test="">` expression to determ if the portlet is currently rendered in the frontend or in the backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `<liferay-theme:defineObjects />` in your JSP pages (otherwise you won't have the `layout` object), you can use this condition:

```
layout.isTypeControlPanel()
```

Comment: thanks... works like charm ;) without the need to add `<liferay-theme:defineObjects />`

Comment: Nice to hear that! And well, I forgot you are customizing the ImageGallery portlet, and so the `defineObjects` taglib is already there, in one of the portal init.jsps..